Why is みた used in this sentence?
そういうえば　お前の私の武器を知りたがってたよなぁ。　実際喰らってみた感想は? ま毒でもともとに喋れないだろうけど
The character taunts the other character after stabbing him with this. He said he has previously wanting to now his weapon and now he finally did.
Then he asks 実際喰らってみた感想は? My understand is that he's saying "How does it feel to actually taste it"? but why てみた, "try to" used? The character didn't try to  get stabbed.

If you didn't know てみた as an idiom for 'try', how would you translate it?

''How did it feel to actually try and taste it'' is my guess.

てみる never means "try to".

The English word "try" conflates some different ideas.
One is "have the experience of something", so as to know what it's like. That's the sense connoted by 〜てみた. The underlying verb is 見る - that is, you do something and then see, metaphorically, what the result is.
Another is "attempt", as in act with the goal of doing something, with no certainty of success. There are a variety of verbs you could use in Japanese for this, with varying specific nuance. It's also sometimes expressed using the volitional + とする.
A Youtube video, for example, of a song cover might be labelled as [歌]{うた}ってみた. Before the recording, it was uncertain how the result would sound, but there was no doubt in the singer's mind of succeeding at the physical act of singing.
(Related: What is the difference between "verb＋て＋みる" and "verb＋(よ)う+とする"?)
Our taunter is asking generically (〜は？) about a particular kind of 感想 "impression"; specifically the other party's impression of 実際喰らってみた - i.e., actually (実際) having experienced (〜てみた, in past tense) an event of [食]{く}らう. Notice that the latter doesn't only mean eating or drinking something voraciously, as the 食 kanji might suggest - it can also refer metaphorically to getting hit, or otherwise being on the receiving end of something bad. (Compare how [頂]{いただ}く can conversely refer to eating or drinking; also compare English idioms like "eat an attack" or "eat dirt" - or less polite variants).
I'm not sure where you get "taste" from. That should probably be [味]{あじ}わう or [舐]{な}める depending on nuance. Eating and tasting are separate things.
